# Отладка дебажной DLL из релизного EXE

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015

Имеется сторонняя программа, написанная на C#. Один исполняемый модуль и кучка DLL. Одну из них стало нужно добавить код. Я декомпилировал нужную DLL, собрал ее в отладочном режиме. В настройках прописал запуск внешней программы, того самого исполняемого модуля, дебажную DLL на всякий случай скопировал в рабочий каталог программы. Запускаю отладку, а Visual мне и говорит, мол, ты релизную версию на отладку запустил. А я релиз вообще не собирал. Никто не подскажет, где я мог лохануться? Сразу скажу, что DLL в последний раз писал и отлаживал в прошлом веке, а шарповую, естественно, вообще в первый раз.

Comment: Ну как бы все ок, вы дебагаете релизный exe-ник, котрый подтягивет дебажную dll. Студия ругнется, но дебагать будет.

Comment: При старте она все брейкпойнты дизейблит. Это нормально?

Comment: Стоит посмотреть окно модулей, посмотреть откуда там вытянуло dll, подгрузился ли pdb. Если нет - подгрузить

Answer (score 1):

Файл dll, собранный студией, должен совпадать с тем, который был загружен процессом. Сложность в том, что при запуске отладки студия может тихонько пересобрать dll, и магии не случится.

Тут есть четыре решения.

1. Прописать в настройках проекта автоматическое копирование библиотеки в папку с внешней программой (тут могут быть проблемы с совместной работой, ведь настройки сборки - общие для всех)
2. Наоборот, скопировать внешнюю программу в выходную папку библиотеки
3. Не запускать отладку через студию, а запускать внешний процесс самостоятельно, после чего "цепляться" к нему во время работы.
4. То же, что и в п.3 - но поставить в нужном месте библиотеки вызов [`Debugger.Launch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx) чтобы библиотека сама подключала отладчик.

---

Еще одна возможная проблема - чужая программа может загружать библиотеку не в основном, а в дочернем процессе. В таком случае помогут только варианты 3 или 4.